# Adding all solutions of N Queen Problem to an arrayList

Tags: java, algorithm, pass-by-reference, backtracking, pass-by-value

The n-queens puzzle is the problem of placing n queens on a (n×n) chessboard such that no two queens can attack each other.

I used backtracking to solve the problem. But I ran in a strange issue.

Below is the code I wrote:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class NQueenProblem {

    static ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> ans = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();

    static ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> nQueen(int n) {

        ArrayList<Integer> positions = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        //boolean[][] placed = new boolean[n][n];
        solveNQueenRec(n, 0, new boolean[n][n], positions);
        //for dubugging purpose. This prints empty arrays. not able to understand why?
        for (ArrayList<Integer> list : ans)
            System.out.println(list);
        return ans;
    }

    static void solveNQueenRec(int n, int col, boolean[][] placed, ArrayList<Integer> positions) {
        if (col == n) {
            //for debugging process
            System.out.println("Adding " + positions);
            ans.add(positions);
            System.out.println("Added " + positions);
        }
        for (int row = 0; row < n && col < n; row++) {
            if (isSafe(row, col, placed, n)) {
                placed[row][col] = true;
                positions.add(row + 1);
                solveNQueenRec(n, col + 1, placed, positions);
                placed[row][col] = false;
                positions.remove(positions.size() - 1);
            }
        }
        // return null;
    }

    private static boolean isSafe(int row, int col, boolean[][] placed, int n) {
        boolean safe = true;
        // checking if exists in same row
        for (int i = 0; i < col; i++) {
            if (placed[row][i])
                safe = false;
        }
        // checking for upper diagonal
        for (int i = row, j = col; i >= 0 && j >= 0; i--, j--) {
            if (placed[i][j])
                safe = false;
        }
        // checking for lower diagonal
        for (int i = row, j = col; i < n && j >= 0; i++, j--) {
            if (placed[i][j])
                safe = false;
        }
        return safe;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        nQueen(4);

    }

}
```

What I am not able to understand is why my ans is empty when I could see in logs list being added to my ans.  Am I doing some silly mistake. Please help me with the issue. If possible please help me with links to understand the issue and how could I avoid these issues in future.

Comment: each time you add an item to `positions` you also remove an item, so it ends up empty, as your println shows.

Answer (score 2):

I think you believe that when the JVM executes

```
   ans.add(positions);
```

that it is taking a copy of the current state of `positions` and adding it to the list. It isn't, it is doing exactly what the code says: adding a reference to an `ArrayList` to `ans`.

All the items in `ans` are references to the same `ArrayList`, and that array list is empty when you print out `ans`.

Answer (score 1):

```
ans.add(positions);
```

is your "problem". You are just adding to `ans` a reference to the list `positions`. Thus `ans` is full of references to the same `positions` list. As you modify `positions` several time after insertion, until emptied it, at the end `ans` is full of *n* references (*n* being the number of solutions found) the same `positions` list that is empty at the end.

What you need is to insert a copy of the current `positions` list at the time a solution is found:

```
ans.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(positions));
```

copy is obtained by constructing a new list with the exact content of the original one.

Answer (score -1):

Add this checking make sure it is greater than zero, then print out the answer. Moreover, add the print queen function, your will see the answer clearly. If this solve your problem, please make as answer.

```
for (ArrayList<Integer> list : ans) {
    if (list.size() > 0)
        System.out.println(list);
}

static void solveNQueenRec(int n, int col, boolean[][] placed, ArrayList<Integer> positions) {
    if (col == n) 
        printQueens(positions);
    
    for (int row = 0; row < n && col < n; row++) {
        if (isSafe(row, col, placed, n)) {
            placed[row][col] = true;
            positions.add(row + 1);
            solveNQueenRec(n, col + 1, placed, positions);
            placed[row][col] = false;
            positions.remove(positions.size() - 1);
        }
    }
    // return null;
}


public static void printQueens(ArrayList<Integer> q) {
    int n = q.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
            if (q.get(i) == j) 
                System.out.print("Q ");
            else           
                System.out.print("* ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }  
    System.out.println();
}

solution to 4-queens sample:
* Q * * 
* * * Q 
Q * * * 
* * Q * 

* * Q * 
Q * * * 
* * * Q 
* Q * *
```

Comment: This is not the OPs problem at all.

Comment: After modify the code, the answer will be correct : Adding [2, 4, 1, 3]
Added [2, 4, 1, 3]
Adding [3, 1, 4, 2]
Added [3, 1, 4, 2]

Comment: "What I am not able to understand is why my ans is empty when I could see in logs list being added to my ans" That is the OPs question, which you haven't answered.

Comment: Because there is  no solution  to print out.

Comment: Try to print queens on the board. Don't add to ans list. since only two solutions to 4-queens and the list size is 4, so two empty list [] will return. Am I clear?

Comment: @chanric "don't ass to ans list", this is exactly what OP wants. He need a list of solutions, not printing them.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès just check if (list.size() > 0) before print the ans list.